# get zoom level and center point from browser console for mapbox

Tags: r, mapbox-gl-js, deck.gl, mapdeck

I'm using Rmarkdown to make a report with mapdeck which uses javascript libraries (deckgl,mapboxgl, etc) to create maps.

Once I generate the map object I can scroll and zoom around and inspect the window.  What'd I'd like to do is after I scroll and zoom, extract the current zoom and center location from the browser console/inspect window so I can hard code that as a starting point.  As it is, I'm constantly guessing and checking (lots of rerendering the map) a starting location and zoom level to fine tune the starting point which seems unnecessary.

I found in the console `mapboxgl.getZoom` but that comes back as undefined.  Is it possible to get that info from the console?

Comment: `mapdeck(show_view_state = TRUE)` will show you the current 'view' state. [Feature request](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/mapdeck/issues/238)

Comment: @SymbolixAU whoa that's pretty awesome.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `show_view_state = TRUE` to get a live overlay of the view's "state"

```
mapdeck(show_view_state = TRUE)
```

[image]